# Install Ubuntu on HDD on a laptop having Windows 10 already installed on a SSD

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, grub

I have recently purchased a new laptop and it came with windows 10 pro installed on a 512 GB SSD. I wish to dual boot the system and install Ubuntu partition on my HDD. I am concerned that the grub installed in the process might not detect windows which is present on another drive (SSD). If I install Ubuntu using a bootable USB using the option "Install Alongside Windows" will it configure properly and will the Grub show up on startup with entries for both Ubuntu and Windows?

Answer (score 0):

This way it should go right. But before you proceed, do two things:

1. read license key from this Windows and note it down for future
2. do a backup of system partitions, so you would not have problem installing Windows in the future

First you can do using ProduKey software by nirsoft, second you can do from Live Linux writing the images of partitions to an external USB drive (for example).

Comment: Hi, I tried doing that, but while installing Ubuntu from a USB, I don't get the option of "Installing alongside Windows".  I only get a screen which says /dev/sdb. I think it's not detecting windows at all.

Comment: Then you have to create separate partitions for Ubuntu manually.

Comment: Since it did not detect Windows at all, I think it might overwrite the current installation and I might not be able to access Windows at all.

Comment: It depends on how you set up the installation.